# Get Left Right values from Jquery plugin-picadiff to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the JQuery plugin picadiff diff tool which is used to compare and find the differences between two blocks of plain text.

```
$.fn.picadiff = function(options) {
    if (window['WebFont'] !== undefined) {
        WebFont.load({
            google : {
                families : [ 'Source Code Pro' ]
            }
        });
    }
    return this.each(function($this) {
        var $this = $(this).addClass('picadiff');
        var settings = {
            leftContainer : '.left', rightContainer : '.right',
            titleContainer : '.picadiff-title',contentContainer : '.picadiff-content',
            lineLength : 40,wrap : false
        };
        if (options) {
            $.extend(settings, options);
        }
        var referenceData = {
            leftTitle : settings.leftTitle || $this.find(settings.titleContainer + ' ' + settings.leftContainer).text(),
            left : settings.leftContent || $this.find(settings.contentContainer + ' ' + settings.leftContainer).text(),
            rightTitle : settings.rightTitle || $this.find(settings.titleContainer + ' ' + settings.rightContainer).text(),
            right : settings.rightContent || $this.find(settings.contentContainer + ' ' + settings.rightContainer).text()
        };

        var compareData = new CompareData(referenceData, settings);
        var lineLength = settings.lineLength;
        var html_texts = settings.wrap ? compareData.getHtmlTextStrict(lineLength) : compareData.getHtmlTexts(lineLength);
        var left = html_texts.source_html;
        var right = html_texts.diss_html;

        $(settings.contentContainer + " " + settings.leftContainer).html(left);
        $(settings.contentContainer + " " + settings.rightContainer).html(right);
        $(settings.titleContainer + " " + settings.leftContainer).html(compareData.leftTitle);
        $(settings.titleContainer + " " + settings.rightContainer).html(compareData.rightTitle);
    });
}; })(jQuery);
```

The output is loading in picadiff-content, but i need only the **left** and **right** value from this method to javascript (to show this value in jsp in own defined textarea). I have called this plugin in js file as like below :

```
$('.picadiff').picadiff({ 
     leftContent: left, 
     rightContent: right
});
```